# Can't open downloaded pdf attachment

Tags: php, pdf

I my PHP application following code is for downloading file attachment. File content and info are stored in MySQL database as blob data.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $attachment['name']. '"');
header('Content-Type: ' . $attachment['type']);
header('Content-Length: ' .$attachment['size']);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
print $attachment['content'];
exit;
```

Download works as expected but pdf files with version 1.4 shows blank content. In case of pdf version 1.3 it works.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have verified that the content downloaded are the same as the content of the PDF in the database *and* are the same as the content uploaded?

Comment: How to verify with original document ? File size is different for corrupted file

Comment: seems like you pdf generator works in a specific way...that 1.3 version recognize it, but 1.4 - dont.

Comment: Do supply a sample of the PDF in question, one copy as it is in the database and one as it is after download.